# Ruby Mysql Connection

Tags: mysql, ruby

I setup ruby and mysql on my mac and i am having issues connecting to my local mysql server.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mysql'
...    
db = Mysql.new("localhost", "root", "", "")
...
```

This would give me the following error when i run this script fromt he command line:

```
generate.rb:37:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (4 for 0) (ArgumentError)
from generate.rb:37:in `new'
from generate.rb:37
```

I have no idea why i am getting this error...any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
db = Mysql.connect("localhost", "root", "", "")
```

?

Comment: that gives:
generate.rb:37: undefined method `connect' for Mysql:Class (NoMethodError)

Comment: Hmm, I wonder what MySQL connector you are using. What does `sudo gem spec mysql` say?

Comment: lenny:script gprime$ sudo gem spec mysql
Password:
--- !ruby/object:Gem::Specification 
name: mysql
version: !ruby/object:Gem::Version 
  hash: 45
  prerelease: false
  segments: 
  - 2
  - 8
  - 1
  version: 2.8.1
platform: ruby
authors: 
- TOMITA Masahiro
autorequire: 
bindir: bin
cert_chain: []


...

Comment: That makes in even more strange because according to http://www.tmtm.org/en/mysql/ruby/ there really should be a connect method on Mysql.

Comment: Also it seems Masahiro has moved to github http://github.com/tmtm/ruby-mysql#readme but it also seems lack english documentation.

Answer (score 1):

reinstall mysql with command

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql -- \
  --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql --with-mysql-lib=/usr/local/mysql/lib \
  --with-mysql-include=/usr/local/mysql/include
```

i've found the solution here http://thinlight.org/2010/05/12/how-to-install-ruby-mysql-on-mac-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard/

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. Uninstalling mysql gem and installing ruby-mysql solved the issue.

sudo gem uninstall mysql

sudo gem install ruby-mysql

Answer (score 0):

You have clear message about wrong number of arguments to `new` method. Maybe try different method? `real_connect` for example.

```
db = Mysql.real_connect('localhost', 'test', 'test', 'testdb');
```

user: test, pass: test, db: testdb

Comment: nah, that did not work either
generate.rb:37: undefined method `real_connect' for Mysql:Class (NoMethodError)

maybe i should reinstall everything, seems like i am missing a lot of stuff

Comment: require 'mysql' is passing so module is loaded, at least it seems that way. Odd. I tested that example and it worked for me (of course different credentials but it is irrelevant).